# How to draw a rectangle in OpenGL with rounded corners?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I want to draw a rectangle with rounded corners. An example is this:

[image: rect]

For reasons, I prefer to use intermediate mode, but shaders are fine either.
How can I do so in OpenGL? I want to have a method like:

```
public static void drawRectWithRoundedCorners(float x, float y, float width, float height, float radius, Color color) {
    // code
}
```

I could not find any instructions on it.

I tried to use a texture, the problem was the corners also got stretched so now I cannot use an image.

Comment: You create geometry for the circumference and render it ... so shorten the rectangle lines by radius from all sides and add circular arc using circle parametric equation ... (~36 lines per whole circle is usually enough), another option is use shaders and compute the distance to rounded rectangle in fragment shader and simply `discard;` pixels outside...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create geometry for the circumference and render it ... so shorten the rectangle lines by radius from all sides and add circular arc using circle parametric equation ... (~36 lines per whole circle is usually enough), another option is use shaders and compute the distance to rounded rectangle in fragment shader and simply `discard;` pixels outside...

I do not code in JAVA but C++ is close enough so here C++/old api GL example:

```cpp
void drawRectWithRoundedCorners(float cx,float cy, float dx, float dy, float r,unsigned __int32 rgba)
    {
    int i;
    float x0,y0,x,y,a=0.0;
    const int n=9;
    const float da=1.5707963267948966192313216916398/float(n);
    dx-=r+r;
    dy-=r+r;
    glColor4ubv((unsigned __int8*)(&rgba));
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex2f(cx,cy);
    x0=cx+(0.5*dx);
    y0=cy+(0.5*dy);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++,a+=da)
        {
        x=x0+(r*cos(a));
        y=y0+(r*sin(a));
        glVertex2f(x,y);
        }
    x0-=dx;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++,a+=da)
        {
        x=x0+(r*cos(a));
        y=y0+(r*sin(a));
        glVertex2f(x,y);
        }
    y0-=dy;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++,a+=da)
        {
        x=x0+(r*cos(a));
        y=y0+(r*sin(a));
        glVertex2f(x,y);
        }
    x0+=dx;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++,a+=da)
        {
        x=x0+(r*cos(a));
        y=y0+(r*sin(a));
        glVertex2f(x,y);
        }
    glVertex2f(x,cy+(0.5*dy));
    glEnd();
    }
```

to improve speed you could have the 36 `cos` and `sin` values hardcoded in a table and as `cos` is just shifted `sin` you can do this:

```cpp
void drawRectWithRoundedCorners(float cx,float cy, float dx, float dy, float r,unsigned __int32 rgba)
    {
    int i;
    float x0,y0,x,y;
    static const float sina[45]={0,0.1736482,0.3420201,0.5,0.6427876,0.7660444,0.8660254,0.9396926,0.9848077,1,0.9848078,0.9396927,0.8660255,0.7660446,0.6427878,0.5000002,0.3420205,0.1736485,3.894144E-07,-0.1736478,-0.3420197,-0.4999996,-0.6427872,-0.7660443,-0.8660252,-0.9396925,-0.9848077,-1,-0.9848078,-0.9396928,-0.8660257,-0.7660449,-0.6427881,-0.5000006,-0.3420208,-0.1736489,0,0.1736482,0.3420201,0.5,0.6427876,0.7660444,0.8660254,0.9396926,0.9848077};
    static const float *cosa=sina+9;
    dx-=r+r;
    dy-=r+r;
    glColor4ubv((unsigned __int8*)(&rgba));
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex2f(cx,cy);
    x0=cx+(0.5*dx);
    y0=cy+(0.5*dy);
    for (i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
        x=x0+(r*cosa[i]);
        y=y0+(r*sina[i]);
        glVertex2f(x,y);
        }
    x0-=dx;
    for (;i<18;i++)
        {
        x=x0+(r*cosa[i]);
        y=y0+(r*sina[i]);
        glVertex2f(x,y);
        }
    y0-=dy;
    for (;i<27;i++)
        {
        x=x0+(r*cosa[i]);
        y=y0+(r*sina[i]);
        glVertex2f(x,y);
        }
    x0+=dx;
    for (;i<36;i++)
        {
        x=x0+(r*cosa[i]);
        y=y0+(r*sina[i]);
        glVertex2f(x,y);
        }
    glVertex2f(x,cy+(0.5*dy));
    glEnd();
    }
```

This is preview of `drawRectWithRoundedCorners(200,200,100,50,10,0x00204080);`:

[image: preview]